# Async function happening before another async function is done in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Now I realy don't know about async/await in node.js to be honest but I'm stuck :(

this is my code

```
async function main(){
    var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon();

    getJSON(pokemonID)
        .then(data => {getPokemonInfo(data)})
        const tempData = require('./temp_data.json');
        await down.load(tempData.pokemonImg)
        var tweetText = "Today's Pokemon of the day is " + tempData.pokemonName + ", which is a " + tempData.pokemonType + " type pokemon"
        await tweet.tweeter(tweetText)

}

main()
```

I don't get an error but the second async function executes before the first one.

Comment: Isn't that the point of "asynchronous"? Also, what is "the first" and "the second"? You show a lot of undeclared identifiers.

Comment: is getRandomPokemon an asynchronous function ?

Comment: yea i know but for it to work i need to run it synchronously

Comment: Also your indentation is a direct path to disaster.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Consider not mixing `then` and await?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `await` also with `getJSON`

```js
async function main(){
    var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon();

    await getJSON(pokemonID)                     //set await 
        .then(data => {getPokemonInfo(data)})
        const tempData = require('./temp_data.json');
        await down.load(tempData.pokemonImg)
        var tweetText = "Today's Pokemon of the day is " + tempData.pokemonName + ", which is a " + tempData.pokemonType + " type pokemon"
        await tweet.tweeter(tweetText)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function main(){
 var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon();
 try {    
   const data = await getJSON(pokemonID);
   const pakemonData =  getPokemonInfo(data)
   const tempData = require('./temp_data.json');
   await down.load(tempData.pokemonImg)
   var tweetText = "Today's Pokemon of the day is " + tempData.pokemonName + ", which is a " + tempData.pokemonType + " type pokemon"
   await tweet.tweeter(tweetText)
 } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)}
}
```

Comment: you should wrap your `await` inside try/catch

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :
Instead of using :

```
getJSON(pokemonID)
        .then(data => {getPokemonInfo(data)})
```

you should use :

```
const data = await getJSON(pokemonId);
// if getPokemonInfo() is asynchronous, use await, if not remove it
await getPokemonInfo(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inside an async function, you can await any other async functions if you want them to execute sequentially.

```js
async function main(){
    var pokemonID = getRandomPokemon(); // if this is asynchronous then modify this to await getRandomPokemon();

    var data = await getJSON(pokemonID);
    var info = await getPokemonInfo(data); // assuming this is async as well, if not then remove the await
    
    const tempData = require('./temp_data.json');
    await down.load(tempData.pokemonImg);
    var tweetText = "Today's Pokemon of the day is " + tempData.pokemonName + ", which is a " + tempData.pokemonType + " type pokemon";
    await tweet.tweeter(tweetText);

}

main();
```